# Google analytics 4 Offline conversion tracking via measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics-4

I'm trying to send a conversion event from Salesforce to GA4 using the measurement protocol, but I'm having trouble creating a payload that can identify the original session that generated a lead (which later converted in Salesforce).

Currently, I'm using GTM to pick up the CID and send it along with the lead to Salesforce. When the lead converts, the CID is sent back along with the "offline conversion" event to GA4.

However, my client wants to be able to link the session that generated the lead to the conversion. For example, if I visit a site three times using the same CID and submit a lead on my second visit, I need to be able to associate that second visit with the eventual conversion.

Unfortunately, there's no clear session ID value in GA4 that I can use similar to the CID. So, I'm planning to include a timestamp with the CID from Salesforce. But the problem is that timestamps can allow events to be backdated up to three calendar days based on the property's timezone. This creates an issue if it takes two weeks or more for the lead to convert.

In summary, I'm looking for a solution to link the session that generated the lead to the eventual conversion, despite the lack of a clear session ID value in GA4. Hope someone can chime in.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi in order to link the session you would need to include the session_id in the request to the Measurement Protocol.

You can get the sessionID using a few method

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#get

or getting the sessionID from the GA4 Cookie.